# React programming pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, react.js

I create https://github.com/storenth/react-redux-todo and ask to review my Todo-react-app for programming pattern: dividing components into presentational components and container components.

Here’s the basic idea behind it: if a component has to have state, make calculations based on props, or manage any other complex logic, then that component shouldn’t also have to render HTML-like JSX.

Instead of rendering HTML-like JSX, the component should render another component. It should be that component’s job to render HTML-like JSX.

So, my question about the `/containers/TodosContainer` that contains `/components/Todos` and `/components/AddForm`. Does it match the pattern? I didn't get where to place the `AddForm`, inside `/components/Todos` (to complex I guess)?

````
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Todos } from "../components/Todos";
import { AddForm } from "../components/AddForm";

export class TodosContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { items: [], text: '' };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            text: e.target.value
        })
    }
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (this.state.text.length === 0) {
            return;
        }
        const newItem = {
            text: this.state.text,
            id: Date.now()
        };
        this.setState({
            items: this.state.items.concat(newItem),
            text: ''
        })
    }
    removeItem = (id) => {
        const items = this.state.items.filter(item => {
            return item.id !== id;
        })
        this.setState({
            items
        })
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Todos items={this.state.items} removeItem={this.removeItem} />
                <AddForm items={this.state} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </>
        )
    }
}
```
````

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @BCdotWEB will be very helpful you start to editing my post.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say, if it's the [Presentation and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) pattern as described by Dan Abramov, then yes, you've pretty effectively nailed it. (*Though Dan no longer advocates this pattern!!*)

## Suggestions/Review

### AddForm

`items` prop is really the `text` state in the parent component, it doesn't need the entire state object. (If it does then name it more accurately!) What's used is *just* the input value, so `value` is a better descriptor.

```
export const AddForm = ({ value, onSubmit, onChange }) => {
  console.log(value);
  return (
    <div className="add-item-form">
      <form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
        <label htmlFor="name">Add new todo:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="name"
          onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          value={value}
        />
        <button
          className="btn waves-effect waves-light"
          type="submit"
          name="action"
        >
          Add item
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Usage: `<AddForm value={this.state.text}  ...  />`

### TodosContainer

The handlers are all arrow functions, they already have the `this` of the class bound to them, so there isn't need to bind them in a constructor. In fact, if all the constructor is doing is setting the initial state, then you don't really need the constructor either as you can simply set initial state with a state instance variable.

Instead of

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { items: [], text: '' };
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
}
```

Simply

```
state = { items: [], text: '' };
```

#### State updates

When *any* next state depends upon current state, like incrementing counters, or adding values to arrays, you should get into the habit of using functional state updates, and also not referencing `this.state` within the state update.

[State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)
[setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

`handleSubmit` can be improved

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const newItem = {
    text: this.state.text,
    id: Date.now(),
  };
  if (this.state.text) { // <-- if text is truthy, i.e. non-empty string
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      items: prevState.items.concat(newItem), 
    }));
  }
}
```

State updates are also asynchronous, so don't try to console.log it after requesting the state update. Use a component lifecycle like `componentDidUpdate` to log state after the update (or for class-based components, you *can* use the setState 2nd parameter callback function, but for simplicity sake stick to the lifecycle functions.).

`removeItem` handler can be improved

```
removeItem = (id) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    items: prevState.items.filter(item => item.id !== id),
  }));
}
```

Comment: I will review your answer more closely in a while, thank you. And, yes, in 2019 update, Dan Abramov told us use pattern without dogmatic fervor.